# How to debug error 403 for subdomain with Tinymce embedded?

Tags: php

when using iframe embedded on live server, I get a 403 error, however, on local host I am able to submit the embedded content through Tinymce.

Comment: Please edit the question to show what you're doing and the error messages. Check how to provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example.

Comment: it was solved via ticket to namecheap.